# How can I remove a part of a string using preg in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to take out GP123 (a string consisting of digits and characters in any order) from a bigger string ($str) and exclude Hello ($str1) which will be a string in another variable.
My code is this. But it is not working. How can I remove a part of a string.

```
$str=" HelloGP123";
$str1="Hello";
preg_match_all("/(?:$str1)\w+\d+\w+/",$str,$str2);
print_r($str2);
```

Comment: So you're looking to return an array of substrings that are made only of alphanumeric characters, but to exclude ignore anything that is part of a given string in the text you're searching?

Comment: yes I just want GP123 as $str2 and exclude Hello. How do I negate $str1 from $str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well My need was just to erase $str1(Hello) part from $str (HelloGP123) and store final remainder in $str2. And I was going all around Regular Expression.

But I realized this can be solved in a much easier way by string replacement.
So here is what I did and it worked.

```
$str2= str_ireplace($str1, '', $str);
```

I guess this is the most easiest method than storming our brain by trying various combinations of regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/hello/","","hellogp123");
```

Why not the above one?

Comment: But how do I do it with variable. This works I know but Suppose I don't know the term Hello that is before GP123 but I know it is the contents of a variable $str1. Then ? Giving a variable to the pattern do not work

Comment: It will work, check the following `$str="hello"; echo preg_replace("/$str/","","hellogp123");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = sprintf('/(?<=%s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', preg_quote($str1, '/'));

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    $str2 = $matches[0];
}
```

This will match any combination of letters and / or numbers but only those immediately following the string contained in `$str1`.

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/okY8TP

Also see - http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: No I don't want to replace GP123 but exclude Hello that is contained in a variable $str1. The new result i.e, GP123 should be stored in $str2. See my code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string="HelloGP123";
$pattern="/Hello/";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

Comment: But how do I do it with variable. This works  I know but Suppose I don't know the term Hello that is before GP123 but I know it is the contents of a variable $str1. Then ? Giving a variable to the pattern do not work

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons that your code doesn't work:

- Firstly `(?:$str1)` is actually attempting to match 'hello' in the string. This is because `(?:)` is a non-capturing subpattern, which *doesn't* mean that anything in the result doesn't get returned (which seems to be how you're trying to use it), but that the subpattern does not return as its own entry in the array of matches.
- `\w+\d+\w+` means "one or more word characters, followed by one or more digit, followed by one or more word character", where a 'word' character is a letter, a number or an underscore. This is not what you say you're trying to match.

Here's some code that will do what you're saying:

```
$str_minus_str1 = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($str1,'/').'/',' ',$str);
preg_match_all('/[0-9A-Za-z]+/',$str_minus_str1,$matches);
```

Note that I've replaced $str1 with ' ' in the string rather than removing it, since if $str was, for example, "applehellobanana", you would want to return 'apple' and 'banana' as separate matches, rather than just matching 'applebanana'.

If you want to return the whole thing as a single string, which appears to be your intention then you'll need to implode your matches with something along the lines of

```
$str2 = implode('',$matches);
```